# Setting the selected value in dropdown after save

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to display the selected value of the dropdown after saving the data in db.
below is my code.

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="customer in user.customers track by $index">
    <td class="tableTd" ng-show="customer.quoteApprovalLevels">{{customer.ic01}} ({{customer.customerName}})</td>
    <td class="tableTd" ng-show="customer.quoteApprovalLevels">
      <select ng-model="user.customers[$index].userQuoteApprovalLevel.approvalLevel">
        <option ng-repeat="approvalLevel in customer.quoteApprovalLevels" value="{{approvalLevel.approvalLevel}}">
          {{approvalLevel.approvalLabel}} - {{approvalLevel.approvalLevel}}
        </option>
      </select>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the js code is

```
$scope.user = Administration.save($scope.user, function (data, httpResponse)     
{
}
```

Comment: where is the code of drop down?

Comment: <select ng-model="user.customers[$index].userQuoteApprovalLevel.approvalLevel" >
                  <option  ng-repeat="approvalLevel in customer.quoteApprovalLevels"  value="{{approvalLevel.approvalLevel}}">
                    {{approvalLevel.approvalLabel}} - {{approvalLevel.approvalLevel}}
                  </option>

Comment: @NehaDagar edit in question

Comment: It was there, just not properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="customer in user.customers track by $index">
    <td class="tableTd" ng-show="user.customers[$index].userQuoteApprovalLevel.approvalLevel">{{customer.ic01}} ({{customer.customerName}})</td>
    <td class="tableTd" ng-show="customer.quoteApprovalLevels">
      <select ng-model="user.customers[$index].userQuoteApprovalLevel.approvalLevel">
        <option ng-repeat="approvalLevel in customer.quoteApprovalLevels" value="{{approvalLevel.approvalLevel}}">
          {{approvalLevel.approvalLabel}} - {{approvalLevel.approvalLevel}}
        </option>
      </select>
  </tr>
</table>
```